# Use class as a property in another class

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a little class that has two properties

```
  public class ColorPair
  {
    #region Miembros

  private Color _BackColor;
  private Color _ForeColor;

  #endregion

  #region Auxiliares

  [Browsable(true)]
  [Category("Color pair")]
  [Description("Back color")]
  [DefaultValue(typeof(Color), "White")]
  public Color BackColor
  {
     get { return _BackColor; }
     set{ _BackColor = value; }
  }

  [Browsable(true)]
  [Category("Color pair")]
  [Description("Fore color")]
  [DefaultValue(typeof(Color), "White")]
  public Color ForeColor
  {
     get { return _ForeColor; }
     set
     {
        _ForeColor = value;
     }
  }

  #endregion

  public ColorPair()
  {
     _BackColor = Color.White;
     _ForeColor = Color.Black;
  }

  public ColorPair(Color pFore, Color pBack)
  {
     _BackColor = pFore;
     _ForeColor = pBack;
  }
```

}

I need to use this as a property in a Control, like this:

```
      [Browsable(true)]
  [Category("Trevo format")]
  [Description("Basic color")]
  [DefaultValue(typeof(ColorPair), "new ColorPair()")]
  public ColorPair Normal
  {
     get { return _Normal; }
     set
     {
        _Normal = value;
        this.Invalidate();
     }
  }
```

But, when I go to the designer, the propery appears disabled. Is there any way to make it enabled to gather the values?

Thank you.

Comment: The designer is not going to know how to display an interface for you to enter these by default...

Comment: You can use a CustomType Provider (don't recall the exact name now); to simplify can't you display two different properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In answer to your question - yes there is a way to make it enabled to gather the values, BUT it involves writing a customer property editor (which will inherit from `UITypeEditor`).

Once you have created this, you can attach it to the property with the `EditorAttribute`.